# What's wrong with keeping frozen vegetables in refrigerator?

Tags: vegetables, frozen, thawing

The bags of frozen mushrooms and okra that I just bought got mistakenly put into the refrigerator for a few days instead of frozen. I want to eat them now.

What's the problem with letting bagged veggies thaw and then eating them? Is there a danger of food poisoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few days, they're almost certainly still safe. Most *fresh* vegetables will last [a few days to a week in the refrigerator](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21068/41).

The *quality* might not be amazing, though. Frozen vegetables tend to get limp and soggy when they thaw; after a few days of being in the refrigerator, they might very well turn to mush once you cook them. But the chances of food poisoning are remote.

Comment: Thanks you Aaronut. The okra turned out ok; however, the mushrooms weren't too good. Still, the dish came together pretty well and I didn't get sick.

Thanks for the speedy answer!